# Calculus of Variations Weierstrass-Erdmann Gelfand and Fomin 3.17

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

The problem is **3.17** from *Calculus of Variations* by Gelfand and Fomin. It states

Find the extremals of the functional

$$ J[y]=\int_0^4(y'-1)^2(y'+1)^2dx,\;\;\;\;\;\;y(0)=0,\;y(4)=2$$

which have just one corner. I have the solution, we know that $J[y]\ge 0$ because it's an integral of a non-negative value. Also $(y'-1)^2(y'+1)^2=0$ if $y'(x)=-1$ or $y'(x)=1$. So as long as $y$ is piecewise lines with these slopes then $J[y]=0$. We just need to make the boundary conditions line up and since there's only a single corner we have 2 segments. So the two solutions are

$$y(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned}&x&&0\leq x\leq 3\\&-x+6&&3\leq x\leq 4\end{aligned}\right.$$
and
$$y(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned}&-x&&0\leq x\leq 3\\&x-2&&3\leq x\leq 4\end{aligned}\right.$$

In both cases $y$ is continuous, single corner, and $J[y]=0$. QED

This derivation is unsatisfactory for me because it uses none of the material (Euler Equation and Weierstrass-Erdman conditions). My goal is to understand the material (not taking a class), so I'm asking for help on how to properly prove this. First, any solution needs to satisfy

$$F_y-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}=0$$

Here $F_y=0$ and after a bunch of tedious work I have $F_{y'}=2y'^3-2y'$. So any solution must solve the differential equation $y'^3-2y'=C$. The solution according to Wolfram Alpha is linear but definitively not unit slope, unless $C$ is $0$. From that point, we would make sure our piece-wise function satisfies

$$F_{y'}|_{x=c-0}=F_{y'}|_{x=c+0}$$
and
$$F-y'F_{y'}|_{x=c-0}=F-y'F_{y'}|_{x=c+0}$$

where $c$ is the point of a discontinous derivative. However,I haven't even bothered with this part since the first part doesn't match. Any suggestions?

Edit: corrected second condition thanks to careful feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a correction: the second [Weierstrass-Erdmann condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%E2%80%93Erdmann_condition) is$^{(*)}$
$$
F-y'F_{y'}|_{x=c-0}=F-y'F_{y'}|_{x=c+0}, \tag{1}
$$
which, for $F=(y'-1)^2(y'+1)^2=(y'^2-1)^2$, yields
$$
(y'^2-1)(1-3y'^2)|_{x=c-0}=(y'^2-1)(1-3y'^2)|_{x=c+0}. \tag{2}
$$
On the other hand, the first Weierstrass-Erdmann condition yields
$$
4y'(y'^2-1)|_{x=c-0}=4y'(y'^2-1)|_{x=c+0}. \tag{3}
$$
It's straightforward to verify that the solutions you found satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equation (see the footnote) and the Weierstrass-Erdmann conditions.

---

$^{(*)}$ A remark is in order here: if $F_x=0$ (as is the case for the given functional), the Euler-Lagrange equation $F_y-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}=0$ can be reduced to the [Beltrami identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity) $F-y'F_{y'}=C$, which is the expression that appears in $(1)$. Therefore, the second Weierstrass-Erdmann condition express the continuity of the constant in the Beltrami identity at the corners of a broken extremal (in the cases where $F_x=0$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Certainly I can see that my solution satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equation. I guess my question was more the other way around, can I go from the Euler-Lagrange equations to my solution? My approach required a lucky Ansatz, which I can't rely on with more complex problems.